# Determining the focal length of a gradient index lens

Tags: optics, lenses

There are three subquestions in this question, all marked bold.

> Let's consider a planoconvex gradient index lens of thickness $d$, radius $R$ whose refractive index changes with the distance from the axis with the following formula
>   $$ n(r) = n_1 + a r^2 $$.
>
> Determine the lens's focal length $f$. Consider only rays falling parallel to the axis, whose distance from it $r_1$ is small. Assume that $\lvert \Delta r \rvert <<d$, $\lvert \Delta r \rvert << r_1$.

First of all, by the Fermat's principle we know that the light will travel with the path, for which the time or, equivalently $\int_X^Y n dS$ is minimal.

So I would say that the ray will approach the axis for $a>0$. But in fact it is the opposite. **Why?**

We can use the principle so as to calculate the focal length. The thickness of the lens depending on the distance from the axis is 
$$x(y) = d + \sqrt{R^2 - y^2} - R \approx d - \frac {y^2}{2R}$$

Let the ray enter the lens at a distance $y$ from the axis at a point $A$. Let it hit the lens's axis at point $B$.
If $f > 0$, then length of the ray's optical path between points $A$ and $B$ is
$$l(y) = x(y) \cdot n(y) + n_0\sqrt{[f + d - x(y)]^2 + y^2}$$ since $\lvert \Delta r \rvert << r_1$.

But if $f<0$ then no ray hits the optical axis (only the rays' extensions). It is claimed that in this case
$$l(y) = x(y) \cdot n(y) - n_0\sqrt{[f + d - x(y)]^2 + y^2}$$

**Why** do we change the sign in this situation?

Later on it is claimed that $f$ is the focal length, then, $l(y)$ does not depend on $y$. **Why?**

Comment: Are you asking about the *focal length*?

Comment: Yes, I do :) Theanks